# How does "would" work in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, modal-verbs

In the sentence "the correct form here would be..", what does 'would' mean?

> A: I've got a doubt concerning a statement to talk about the future: do we say the best student will win a prize or The best student is winning a prize?
>
> Answer: The correct form here **would be** "will win". You would say "is winning" when you are describing the present - i.e. when you are watching the prize-giving.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the word **would** is a modal verb being used to express politeness. Compare the following sentences:

> The correct form here **is** "will win."
>
> The correct form here **would be** "will win".

They mean the same thing, but the second sentence is softer, less direct, and a little more polite.

Comment: Thanks. What is a **less direct**? Is it condtional? Could you explain?

Comment: @whitekrystal Less direct meaning less blunt.

Comment: So, there is no conditional in that sentence, isn't there?

Comment: @whitekrystal Correct, the first sentence is not conditional. The modal verb "would" is being used to express politeness, not possibility.

Comment: Thanks godel9. One more question. I sometimes hear **would** used to be more tentative. What is meant with **tentative**? Could you explain?

Comment: Tentative means uncertain or unsure.

Comment: Thanks. In the sentence "any help would be apprecited", someone says that "would" here is tentative. Does 'would' mean 'posible will'?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75481/discussion-between-whitekrystal-and-godel9).